# image onload not triggering inside of promise

Tags: javascript, promise, onload

Hello I created a promise and call it recursively from a loop to fill an array but the onload never triggers thus never resolving the promise.

Can anyone see anything I'm doing wrong?

```
function imageResizeToDataUriPromise(url, width, height) {

    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {


        var img = new Image();
        img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');

        img.onload = function () {

             var imgWidth = img.naturalWidth;
             var imgHeight = img.naturalHeight;

             var result = _scaleImage(imgWidth, imgHeight, width, height, true);
             //create an off-screen canvas
             var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
             var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

             canvas.width = result.width;
             canvas.height = result.height;

             //draw source image into the off-screen canvas:
             ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, result.width, result.height);

            resolve(canvas.toDataURL());

         };

        img.src = url;

    });
}
```

Comment: Works fine for me. Can you show how you're calling/using the result and what `_scaleImage` is (I just removed it)? Thanks.

Comment: what do you see in your browser developer tools console - any errors regarding your code?

Comment: Its done with Visual Studio 2019 Office Add-Ins framework...thanks guys/gals let me post the calling code

Comment: _scaleImage is a function that allows to proportionalize the image somewhat irrelevant ..I run it in the VS debugger and that could be blocking the images let me check more

Comment: Okay the img.setAttribute('crossOrigin','anonymous'); was blocking but it I removed it then I get a JavaScript Security Error....ahhhhh!!!

Answer (score 0):

It works after I use that promise to get an URL and set it to an image element... not sure how you would use the return Data URL.  One possible issue is: can you check whether your image source is serving you the image. (double check the network tab in developer tool).

```js
function imageResizeToDataUriPromise(url, width, height) {

  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');

    img.onload = function() {
      console.log("IMG ONLOAD handler invoked");
      var imgWidth = img.naturalWidth;
      var imgHeight = img.naturalHeight;

      var result = img;

      //create an off-screen canvas
      var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

      canvas.width = result.width;
      canvas.height = result.height;

      //draw source image into the off-screen canvas:
      ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, result.width, result.height);

      ctx.fillStyle = "white";
      ctx.font = '21px sans-serif';
      ctx.fillText('Hello world', 21, 51);

      resolve(canvas.toDataURL());
    };

    img.src = url;

  });
}

imageResizeToDataUriPromise("https://i.imgur.com/j7Ie7pg.jpg", 100, 100)
  .then(url => document.querySelector("#an-image").src = url);

console.log("Promise obtained");
```

```html
<img id="an-image">
```

Answer (score 0):

this is my basic calling block but its in a loop

```
caller(logo, 150, 150).then
(function (response) {
  console.log("Success!", response);
  base64Urls.push(response);
```

});